# How do I use cbindgen to return and free a Box<Vec<_>>?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a struct returned to C code from Rust. I have no idea if it's a good way to do things, but it does work for rebuilding the struct and freeing memory without leaks.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct s {
    // ...
}

#[repr(C)]
#[allow(clippy::box_vec)]
pub struct s_arr {
    arr: *const s,
    n: i8,
    vec: Box<Vec<s>>,
}

/// Frees memory that was returned to C code
pub unsafe extern "C" fn free_s_arr(a: *mut s_arr) {
    Box::from_raw(s_arr);
}

/// Generates an array for the C code
pub unsafe extern "C" fn gen_s_arr() -> *mut s_arr {
    let many_s: Vec<s> = Vec::new();
    // ... logic here

    Box::into_raw(Box::new(s_arr {
        arr: many_s.as_mut_ptr(),
        n: many_s.len() as i8,
        vec: many_s,
    }))
}
```

The C header is currently written by hand, but I wanted to try out cbindgen. The manual C definition for `s_arr` is:

```c
struct s_arr {
    struct s *arr;
    int8_t n;
    void *_;
};
```

cbindgen generates the following for `s_arr`:

```c
typedef struct Box_Vec_s Box_Vec_s;

typedef struct s_arr {
        const s *arr;
        int8_t n;
        Box_Vec_s vec;
} s_arr;
```

This doesn't work since `struct Box_Vec_s` is not defined. Ideally I would just want to override the cbindgen type generated for `vec` to make it `void *` since it requires no code changes and thus no additional testing, but I am open to other suggestions.

I have looked through the cbindgen documentation, though not the examples, and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think that if I understood you right, you're confusing two things and being led down a dark alley as a result.

In C, a dynamically-sized array, as you probably know, is identified by two things:

1. Its starting position, as a pointer
2. Its length

Rust follows the same convention - a `Vec<_>`, below the hood, shares the same structure (well, almost. It has a capacity as well, but that's beside the point).

Passing the boxed vector **on top** of a pointer is not only overkill, but extremely unwise. FFI bindings may be smart, but they're not smart enough to deal with a boxed complex type most of the time.

To solve this, we're going to simplify your bindings. I've added a single element in `struct S` to show you how it works. I've also cleaned up your FFI boundary:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[no_mangle]
pub struct S {
    foo: u8
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct s_arr {
    arr: *mut S,
    n: usize,
    cap: usize
}

// Retrieve the vector back
pub unsafe extern "C" fn recombine_s_arr(ptr: *mut S, n: usize, cap: usize) -> Vec<S> {
    Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, n, cap)
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn gen_s_arr() -> s_arr {
    let mut many_s: Vec<S> = Vec::new();

    let output = s_arr {
        arr: many_s.as_mut_ptr(),
        n: many_s.len(),
        cap: many_s.capacity()
    };
    std::mem::forget(many_s);
    output
}
```

With this, cbindgen returns the expected header definitions:

```c
typedef struct {
  uint8_t foo;
} so58311426S;

typedef struct {
  so58311426S *arr;
  uintptr_t n;
  uintptr_t cap;
} so58311426s_arr;

so58311426s_arr gen_s_arr(void);
```

This allows us to call `gen_s_arr()` from either C or Rust and retrieve a struct that is usable across both parts of the FFI boundary (`so58311426s_arr`). This struct contains all we need to be able to modify our array of `S` (well, `so58311426S` according to cbindgen).

When passing through FFI, you need to make sure of a few simple things:

- You cannot pass raw boxes or non-primitive types; you will almost universally need to convert down to a set of pointers or change your definitions to accomodate (as I have done here)
- You most *definitely* do not pass raw vectors. At most, you pass a slice, as that is a primitive type (see the point above).
- You make sure to `std::mem::forget()` whatever you do not want to deallocate, and make sure to remember to deallocate it or reform it somewhere else.

I will edit this question in an hour; I have a plane to get on to. Let me know if any of this needs clarifications and I'll get to it once I'm in the right country :-)

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was doing something silly, though when I wrote the original code some months ago I couldn't find a good solution.

For `std::mem::forget(many_s);`, what is the guarantee that this doesn't leak? The only struct member I'd expect to be allocated in heap for Vec would be the dynamic array, but perhaps in the future there is another Vec member on the heap. Do I just trust that the stdlib maintainers will keep Vec this way? This is more an academic question than a practical one - your solution works just fine for my needs.

Comment: @MrTheFoolish I've had the time in the plame to prepare a lot of stuff for you. most of it will answer your questions and probably start a few more :-) I might also turn all this info into articles somewhere, there's so little info on ffi